# If $\mathbf{e}_1\wedge\mathbf{e}_2=\sqrt{|g|}\gamma_1 \wedge\gamma_2$, what is $\mathbf{e}_1$ in terms of $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$ and $g$?

Tags: metric-spaces, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, inner-products, tensors

Suppose:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{e}_1&:=a\gamma_1+b\gamma_2\\
\mathbf{e}_2&:=c\gamma_1+d\gamma_2
\end{align}
$$

It is known that the wedge product $\mathbf{e}_1\wedge\mathbf{e}_2=\sqrt{|g|}\gamma_1 \wedge \gamma_2$ has a 'nice' expression referencing the metric tensor and the determinant.

I suspect that we can write any basis element in any combinations of wedge products in terms of the metric tensor.

Specifically, can we write $\mathbf{e}_1$ in terms of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ and the metric tensor $g$?

For instance, can we write $\mathbf{e}_1$ as an expression along these lines

$$
\mathbf{e}_1\approx g^{\mu\nu} \gamma_\nu
$$

(I know this equation is not the correct one, but I can't figure it out - hence this request for help).

Edit:

What about a linear combination of $\mathbf{e}_1$ and $\mathbf{e_2}$ --- does it have an expression in terms of the metric tensor? For example:

$$
F\mathbf{e}_1+G\mathbf{e}_2=H(g,\gamma_1,\gamma_2)
$$

Edit 2 / attempt:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{e}_1+\mathbf{e}_2&= a\gamma_1+b\gamma_2 + c\gamma_1+d\gamma_2\\
&=(a+c)\gamma_1+(b+d)\gamma_2
\end{align}
$$

The metric tensor is :

$$
g=\pmatrix{a^2+b^2 & ac+db\\ ac+bd & c^2+d^2}
$$

Comment: You don't know anything, since you can add any multiple of $e_2$ to $e_1$.

Comment: @user10354138 does my edit make any difference?

Comment: @user10354138 Can you also specify what you mean with "you don't know anything" - what is the thing which I must know but do not?